# EF 6 codde first - One To Many Mapping - ICollection always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I know this question was asked many times before, but I have a strange behavior at my side and I couldn't get any solution.

I'm building a .Net application with EF6 and code first. I defined my classes as follows (these are example classes but I have exactly the same structure):

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RefId { get; set; }

    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public Grade Grade { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{
    private string _name;

    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I understand that lazy loading is enabled by default beyond ef 4, and the solution that mostly work is to remove the virtual keyword from the entities (non-virtual properties).

In my case, I want to set some custom code in the getter method of the Grade class, but `ICollection<Student> Students` is always null.

For example:

```
public string GradeName
{
    get
    {
        _name = Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.GradeId == GradeId &&
                              s.RefId == 2).Name;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_name))
        {
            _name = Name;
        }

        return _name;
    }

    set => _name = value;
}
```

I tried everything possible, nothing helped. It will be great if you can help me solve this issue, thanks!

Comment: `public` **virtual** `ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }`

Comment: This didn't work. In the getter method GradeName the Students is always null!

Comment: Is `Grade` instance, on which you call `GradeName`, fetched from context?

Comment: I'm developing a Multi Language Feature for an application that already exists. And I want to get the GradeName depending on a RefId. So to avoid changing in each and every existing implementation I want to only change the GradeName getter method. In my controller for example it is like this: var result = db.Grades.ToList(); and in each r in result the r.GradeName should return the value from the custom getter which i posted in my question

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding how lazy vs eager loading works. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).

Marking the collection virtual just means it is deferred. Removing it does not populate the collection, you still need the Include:

```
var studentWithGrade = context.Students
            .Include(s => s.Grade)
            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.GradeId == GradeId && s.RefId == 2);
```

or the grade with the student collection:

```
var gradeWithStudents = context.Grade
            .Include(g => g.Students)
            .ToList();
```

More include combinations [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how can i use the include in my case. I mean in the getter method. Students is always null, how can i populate it to use it in the getter method, see my question again please. At this step i have no context object

Comment: Guess I am not seeing what you are trying to accomplish. You refer to a Students.FirstOrDefault(). Where is that populated?

Comment: Let me Paste the comment that I wrote before and you will know what I want to accomplish

Comment: I'm developing a Multi Language Feature for an application that already exists. And I want to get the GradeName depending on a RefId. So to avoid changing in each and every existing implementation I want to only change the GradeName getter method. In my controller for example it is like this: var result = db.Grades.ToList(); and in each r in result the r.GradeName should return the value from the custom getter which i posted in my question

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize students in the constructor as it's responsibility of the class:

```
public class Grade
{
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public Grade ()
    {
        Students = new Collection<Student>();
    }
}
```

Comment: this will initialize the collection to not give null reference exception, but it will not contain the related data. I already tried it